# Javascript - trying to add array object values together after looping through them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, shopping-cart, checkout

I'm trying to do a mini checkout JavaScript exercise. The user adds 2 or more items together (`checkbox`) options, the price of the items are totaled then returned. For some reason I can't add the values of the array objects together. Everything else in my code work just that 1 section. Can someone please help me? My code is below:

JavaScript

```js
// This Array Object holds the items name and prices the user selects from
var shoppingItems = {
  "Stainless Steel Cooking Pot": 29.99,
  "Mini Stainless Steel Blender": 19.99,
  "Kitchen Towel Set": 7.99,
  "Large Tan Coffee Mug": 5.49,
  "5 Round Dinner Plate Set": 5.99,
  "Salt and Pepper Shaker Set": 1.99,
  "Large Blue Broom": 3.98,
  "Pink Soap Dish": 2.50,
  "Silver Bathroom Trash Can": 6.99,
  "Silk Black Bathroom Robe": 9.99,
};

var itemsSelectedValues = [];
// this is the empty array where the checkbox values will be added to

var total = 0;
 // this is the variable that will hold the items total

function listOfCheckedItems(catalogToLookFrom) {
  var yourItemsPurchased = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  for (i = 0; i < yourItemsPurchased.length; i++) {
      if(yourItemsPurchased[i].checked === true) {
       itemsSelectedValues.push(yourItemsPurchased[i].value);
      } // line closes if statement
  } // line closes for loop
  for (i = 0; i < itemsSelectedValues.length; i++) {
    // line above is suppose to loop through the now full array that has the items value names stored
    total = total + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues];
    // this line is suppose to set variable total to itself + the value of the item that's stored in array shoppingItems. It's suppose to do this each time through the loop. This is where the problem lies. 
  } // closes for loop
  console.log(catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues]);
  return total;
} // line closes listOfCheckedItems function

function getOrderTotal() {
  listOfCheckedItems(shoppingItems);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="cash-register.html" method="post">
    <p style="color:#A569BD; font-size:20px; text-decoration:underline; margin-left:20px;">Department Store Items</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Stainless Steel Cooking Pot">Stainless Steel Cooking Pot - $29.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Mini Stainless Steel Blender">Mini Stainless Steel Blender - $19.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Kitchen Towel Set">Kitchen Towel Set - $7.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Tan Coffee Mug">Large Tan Coffee Mug - $5.49<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="5 Round Dinner Plate Set">5 Round Dinner Plate Set - $5.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Salt and Pepper Shaker Set">Salt and Pepper Shaker Set - $1.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Blue Broom">Large Blue Broom - $3.98<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Pink Soap Dish">Pink Soap Dish - $2.5<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silver Bathroom Trash Can">Silver Bathroom Trash Can - $6.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silk Black Bathroom Robe">Silk Black Bathroom Robe - $9.99
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" name="yourOrder" onclick="getOrderTotal()">Submit</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Try modifying this line to
total = total + Number(catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues]);

Comment: `if(yourItemsPurchased[i].checked === true) {` is unnecessary since the collection is already checked items

Comment: @Kapilgopinath they are all numbers

Comment: @Kapilgopinath Thank you very much!

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the [i] in the loop

`total = total + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];`

Here is a MUCH simplified version

```js
$(function() { // when the page loads
  $("input:checkbox").on("change", function() { // each time something changes
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() { // only checked boxes
      total += shoppingItems[this.value]; // the prices are already numbers
    })
    $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2)); // 2 decimals
  }).change(); // run at load time to calculate
})

// This Array Object holds the items name and prices the user selects from
var shoppingItems = {
  "Stainless Steel Cooking Pot": 29.99,
  "Mini Stainless Steel Blender": 19.99,
  "Kitchen Towel Set": 7.99,
  "Large Tan Coffee Mug": 5.49,
  "5 Round Dinner Plate Set": 5.99,
  "Salt and Pepper Shaker Set": 1.99,
  "Large Blue Broom": 3.98,
  "Pink Soap Dish": 2.50,
  "Silver Bathroom Trash Can": 6.99,
  "Silk Black Bathroom Robe": 9.99,
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="cash-register.html" method="post">
  <p style="color:#A569BD; font-size:20px; text-decoration:underline; margin-left:20px;">Department Store Items</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Stainless Steel Cooking Pot">Stainless Steel Cooking Pot - $29.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Mini Stainless Steel Blender">Mini Stainless Steel Blender - $19.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Kitchen Towel Set">Kitchen Towel Set - $7.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Tan Coffee Mug">Large Tan Coffee Mug - $5.49<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="5 Round Dinner Plate Set">5 Round Dinner Plate Set - $5.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Salt and Pepper Shaker Set">Salt and Pepper Shaker Set - $1.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Blue Broom">Large Blue Broom - $3.98<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Pink Soap Dish">Pink Soap Dish - $2.5<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silver Bathroom Trash Can">Silver Bathroom Trash Can - $6.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silk Black Bathroom Robe">Silk Black Bathroom Robe - $9.99
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" name="yourOrder">Submit</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</form>
Total: $<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Ok I see. My apologies. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation @Aishah91

Comment: I do. I appreciate your code but just out of curiosity do you know why mines didn't work. It seemed like it logically made sense and would work. Just want to know where I went wrong.

Comment: You needed the index as in  `total = total + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a different and more clean logic here.

Once you selected the elements using jQuery, you can iterate over these objects using `.each()` where the `this`context will be directly the element.

Also, you don't need an array with the values, you can simply sum then inside the `each()` function, passing the value of the ones that are selected to the array of `shoppingItems` in a way that you retrieve the $ value. At the end of the iteration, you'll have the total value.

And as said in the comments of my answer, you don't need to check for `this.checked === true` once you selected in jQuery only the ones that are checked.

take a look, please:

```js
var shoppingItems = {
  "Stainless Steel Cooking Pot": 29.99,
  "Mini Stainless Steel Blender": 19.99,
  "Kitchen Towel Set": 7.99,
  "Large Tan Coffee Mug": 5.49,
  "5 Round Dinner Plate Set": 5.99,
  "Salt and Pepper Shaker Set": 1.99,
  "Large Blue Broom": 3.98,
  "Pink Soap Dish": 2.50,
  "Silver Bathroom Trash Can": 6.99,
  "Silk Black Bathroom Robe": 9.99,
};

function listOfCheckedItems(catalogToLookFrom) {
  var yourItemsPurchased = $("input:checkbox:checked");
  var totalValue = 0;
  yourItemsPurchased.each(function(){      
      totalValue += parseFloat(shoppingItems[this.value]);
  }) 
  
  
  console.log(totalValue);
  return totalValue;
}

function getOrderTotal() {
  listOfCheckedItems(shoppingItems);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="cash-register.html" method="post">
    <p style="color:#A569BD; font-size:20px; text-decoration:underline; margin-left:20px;">Department Store Items</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Stainless Steel Cooking Pot">Stainless Steel Cooking Pot - $29.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Mini Stainless Steel Blender">Mini Stainless Steel Blender - $19.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Kitchen Towel Set">Kitchen Towel Set - $7.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Tan Coffee Mug">Large Tan Coffee Mug - $5.49<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="5 Round Dinner Plate Set">5 Round Dinner Plate Set - $5.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Salt and Pepper Shaker Set">Salt and Pepper Shaker Set - $1.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Blue Broom">Large Blue Broom - $3.98<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Pink Soap Dish">Pink Soap Dish - $2.5<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silver Bathroom Trash Can">Silver Bathroom Trash Can - $6.99<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silk Black Bathroom Robe">Silk Black Bathroom Robe - $9.99
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" name="yourOrder" onclick="getOrderTotal()">Submit</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: This test is unnecessary `if(this.checked === true) {
        totalValue += parseFloat(shoppingItems[this.value]);
      } `

Comment: you are right, i let it behind because it was in the original code, but now it's adjusted. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thank you very much! I so appreciate it

Comment: nice to know that I helped you. If you think this answer is the correct one, Thick the "V" mark in the left of my answer

Comment: @mplungjan I just have 2 questions to your code. 1) Why are there two different variables for the total? One is var total the other is var total Value. Also what does parseFloat mean?

Comment: 1) `total` is wrong, you can delete it, it was a remain of the original code, `totalValue` is correct one. (I edited my answer now). 2) parseFloat is just the function that converts a numeric value to a float value (that have decimals), it's optional here, but is useful to ensure the calculations will occur jsut with numbers, not as strings

Comment: @Aishah91 please see my answer. This is NOT my code! Mine is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044201/295783

Comment: @CalvinNunes Ok got it! Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code into a one liner with `array.reduce` (see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for reduce):

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").toArray().reduce((a, e) => a + catalog[e.value], 0)
```

This begins by calling `toArray()` on your jQ collection to turn it into a vanilla array. The `reduce` function called on this array passes each element in the array (`e`) into a callback function. `reduce` also accepts a second parameter `0` which accumulates the final total. This total is passed repeatedly into the `a` parameter of the `reduce` callback and is added to each `e` value taken from the `catalog` object.

```js
var shoppingItems = {
  "Stainless Steel Cooking Pot": 29.99,
  "Mini Stainless Steel Blender": 19.99,
  "Kitchen Towel Set": 7.99,
  "Large Tan Coffee Mug": 5.49,
  "5 Round Dinner Plate Set": 5.99,
  "Salt and Pepper Shaker Set": 1.99,
  "Large Blue Broom": 3.98,
  "Pink Soap Dish": 2.50,
  "Silver Bathroom Trash Can": 6.99,
  "Silk Black Bathroom Robe": 9.99,
};

const listOfCheckedItems = catalog =>
  $("input:checkbox:checked").toArray().reduce((a, e) => a + catalog[e.value], 0)
; 

function getOrderTotal() {
  console.log(listOfCheckedItems(shoppingItems));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="cash-register.html" method="post">
  <p style="color:#A569BD; font-size:20px; text-decoration:underline; margin-left:20px;">Department Store Items</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Stainless Steel Cooking Pot">Stainless Steel Cooking Pot - $29.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Mini Stainless Steel Blender">Mini Stainless Steel Blender - $19.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Kitchen Towel Set">Kitchen Towel Set - $7.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Tan Coffee Mug">Large Tan Coffee Mug - $5.49<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="5 Round Dinner Plate Set">5 Round Dinner Plate Set - $5.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Salt and Pepper Shaker Set">Salt and Pepper Shaker Set - $1.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Large Blue Broom">Large Blue Broom - $3.98<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Pink Soap Dish">Pink Soap Dish - $2.5<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silver Bathroom Trash Can">Silver Bathroom Trash Can - $6.99<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="Silk Black Bathroom Robe">Silk Black Bathroom Robe - $9.99
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" name="yourOrder" onclick="getOrderTotal()">Submit</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: It is highly likely that this is too complex for a noob JS assignment.